# What would happen if very strong electric field is applied to the surface of conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

I know that if the conductor is at the negative end, it can emit electrons (field emission) when the electric field is sufficiently strong. But what if the conductor is at the positive end? Will the surface break down and emit positive ions?

Comment: No no positive ions will emerge. bur what about the other end is there no conductor?

Comment: You can make asymmetric electrodes. One is pointy like a needle while the other is spread out like a phototube. When a voltage is applied to them, the pointy one experiences a much stronger electric field.